# how to combine two List<Map<String,Object>>

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp

**There are these two List<Map<String,Object>> in java**

*List<Map<String,Object>> voListResult = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();*

voListResult:

```
[{product_idx=1, likecheck=0, product_price=25000,  product_title=크롭트 가디건}, 
{product_idx=2, likecheck=0, product_price=25000, product_title=크롭트 가디건}, 
{product_idx=3, likecheck=0, product_price=25000,  product_title=크롭트 가디건}, 
{product_idx=4, likecheck=0, product_price=25000,  product_title=크롭트 가디건}, 
{product_idx=5, likecheck=0, product_price=25000,  product_title=크롭트 가디건}, 
{ product_idx=6, likecheck=0, product_price=25000, , product_title=크롭트 가디건},
 {product_idx=7, likecheck=0, product_price=25000,  product_title=크롭트 가디건}, 
{product_idx=8, likecheck=0, product_price=25000,  product_title=크롭트 가디건}, 
{product_idx=9, likecheck=0, product_price=25000,  product_title=크롭트 가디건}]
```

*List<Map<String, Object>> productLikeRenew = likeDAO.SumProductLike();*

productLikeRenew:

```
[{product_idx=3, likecheck=2}, {product_idx=10, likecheck=2},
{product_idx=12, likecheck=1}, {product_idx=5, likecheck=1},
{product_idx=7, likecheck=1}, {product_idx=11, likecheck=1},
{product_idx=13, likecheck=1},{product_idx=20, likecheck=1},
{product_idx=30, likecheck=1},{product_idx=40, likecheck=1}, 
{product_idx=59, likecheck=1}]
```

**How can I update likecheck based on product_idx of both Lists in voListResult?**

result:

```
[{product_idx=1, likecheck=0, product_price=25000,  product_title=크롭트 가디건}, 
{product_idx=2, likecheck=0, product_price=25000, product_title=크롭트 가디건}, 
{product_idx=3, likecheck=2, product_price=25000,  product_title=크롭트 가디건}, 
{product_idx=4, likecheck=0, product_price=25000,  product_title=크롭트 가디건}, 
{product_idx=5, likecheck=0, product_price=25000,  product_title=크롭트 가디건}, 
{ product_idx=6, likecheck=0, product_price=25000, , product_title=크롭트 가디건},
 {product_idx=7, likecheck=1, product_price=25000,  product_title=크롭트 가디건}, 
{product_idx=8, likecheck=0, product_price=25000,  product_title=크롭트 가디건}, 
{product_idx=9, likecheck=0, product_price=25000,  product_title=크롭트 가디건},
{product_idx=10, likecheck=2, product_price=25000,  product_title=크롭트 가디건}
...]
```

I've been thinking about it for a few days, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you edit your question to provide additional information? like: what are you trying to accomplish? what are those lists supposed to do/represent? What do product_idx and likecheck represent and how are they related?

Comment: The part that is currently shown is in the process of processing data in the service.
I want to show product information after making a form like the result in the question, passing it to the controller, and passing the object from the controller to the view.

I will update the numerical information of likecheck in voListResult with product_idx and likecheck information.

Comment: To me it is confusing. Can you simply provide an input and your desired output?

Comment: I solved it by converting the number of likechecks by combining product_idx using an index. Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following things:-

1. Sort both List of maps based on the product_idx number.
2. define a counter for productLikeRenew and initialize with 0.
3. Iterate voListResult list until product_idx of voListResult <= product_idx of productLikeRenew.
4. If product_idx of both of them is equal then combine the result.
5. Increment the counter.
6. Repeat steps from 3 to 5 until one of the List is ended.